# Adding notation directly under $\arg \min$

Tags: math-operators

How do I add the `$\theta_t \in \Theta$` in `$$\theta_t^* = {\arg \min}_{\theta_t \in \Theta} \mathbb{E}$$` so that it goes directly underneath the `$\arg \min$`?

EDIT: I should have specified this earlier, but I'm primarily interested in something that would work on stackexchange sites, such as math.stackexchange.

Comment: ---ah, but that is MathJax, not TeX --- they are different things that happen to use the same language. More or less ;-)  --- see the tag description: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\limits` can be applied to a math operator, to indicate that sub/super-scripts should go below/above the operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\theta_t^* = \mathop{\arg \min}\limits_{\theta_t \in \Theta} \mathbb{E}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was playing around with \limits, since I've used it before with \sum, but I just couldn't get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could declare a new math operator with the command `\DeclareMathOperator*` from `amsmath`. When the starred version of this command is used, superscripts and subscripts of the new operator are placed as they would be placed with `\limits`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\begin{document}
\[
\theta_t^* = \argmin_{\theta_t \in \Theta} \mathbb{E}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, note that [you should use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: I should have specified, but I was primarily interested in something that would work on stackexchange sites, such as math.stackexchange.